# Button click file is not showing properly in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here the div is creating dynamically getting data from database through corresponding php. It is retrieving the file name and title and displaying in each div. The files are also saved by the same file name in '/testupload/' local directory from where it should be fetched matching the file name through the 'View Detail' button click and the user can view the file. But I failed to implement this. What is happening here when I clicked the button it is showing a specific file for every button. Here goes the Javascript portion of my code.

```
    function view() {
    //location.href = "./testupload/"+nt_name;
    window.location='./testupload/'+nt_name; return false;

}

function dynamic3() {
    //alert(drName.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < total3; i++) {
        var d = new Array(6);
        //var i = 0;

        nt_name = notice_name\[index3\];
        nt_title = notice_title\[index3\];
        index3 = index3 + 1;
        //console.log(name + "      " + type + "      " + sal);
        //console.log(d\[0\] + d\[1\] + d\[2\] + d\[3\] + d\[4\]+ d\[5\]);
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'row';
        div.innerHTML = '<div class="container" >\
                    <div class="bs-calltoaction bs-calltoaction-info">\
                    <div class="row"\
                    <div class="col-sm-12">\
                    <div class="col-md-9 cta-contents">\
                     <h1 class="cta-title">Notice: ' + nt_name + '</h1>\
                     <div class="cta-desc">\
                     <h3>' + nt_title + '</h3>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-md-3 cta-button">\
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" onclick="view()">View Detail</button>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
            </div>';

        document.getElementById('notice_content').appendChild(div);
    }

}
```

[image: Here goes the image of the web page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you attempting to tell the `view()` function to go to the .PDF file? If so, I think you intended to call the function with a param, view(**nt_name**) ... Cant' be positive without seeing the rest of your code.

```
function view(nt_name) {
    window.location='./testupload/'+nt_name; return false;
}

function dynamic3() {
    for (var i = 0; i < total3; i++) {
        var d = new Array(6);

        nt_name = notice_name\[index3\];
        nt_title = notice_title\[index3\];
        index3 = index3 + 1;

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'row';
        div.innerHTML = '<div class="container" >\
                    <div class="bs-calltoaction bs-calltoaction-info">\
                    <div class="row"\
                    <div class="col-sm-12">\
                    <div class="col-md-9 cta-contents">\
                     <h1 class="cta-title">Notice: ' + nt_name + '</h1>\
                     <div class="cta-desc">\
                     <h3>' + nt_title + '</h3>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-md-3 cta-button">\
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" onclick="view(\'' + nt_name + '\')">View Detail</button>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
            </div>';

        document.getElementById('notice_content').appendChild(div);
    }

}
```

Comment: It was a little confusing as the button code is dynamically being generated... I made an edit to the code. The nt_name has to be set as a literal string when creating the button... so added it in escaped single quotes

Comment: Thank you very much your edit version works perfectly. I have wasted so many time for this :')